# How to pass an entire class into an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle, android-fragmentactivity

I have this class:

public class Weather {

```
public Today today = new Today(){};
public Tomorrow tomorrow = new Tomorrow(){};
public DayAfter dayafter = new DayAfter(){};
public DayDayAfter daydayafter = new DayDayAfter(){};

public class Today {
    private String mToday;
    private int mTodayHours;
    private final ArrayList<String> arrTime1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ArrayList<String> arrWind_Speed1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ArrayList<String> arrCloud_Amount1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ArrayList<String> arrPop1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ArrayList<String> arrWind_Gust1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ArrayList<String> arrTemperature1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ArrayList<String> arrWind_Direction1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ArrayList<String> arrWeather1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void putTodayHours(int value){ mTodayHours = value; }
    public int getTodayHours() {return mTodayHours;}
    public String getToday(){ return mToday;}

    public void putToday(String key, String value){
        switch (key) {
            case "today": mToday = value;break;
            case "time":arrTime1.add(value);break;
            case "wind_speed":arrWind_Speed1.add(value);break;
            case "cloud_amount":arrCloud_Amount1.add(value);break;
            case "pop":arrPop1.add(value);break;
            case "wind_gust":arrWind_Gust1.add(value);break;
            case "temperature":arrTemperature1.add(value);break;
            case "wind_direction":arrWind_Direction1.add(value);break;
            case "weather":arrWeather1.add(value);break;
        }
    }
    public ArrayList getToday(String key){
        switch (key){
            case "time": return arrTime1;
            case "wind_speed": return arrWind_Speed1;
            case "cloud_amount": return arrCloud_Amount1;
            case "pop": return arrPop1;
            case "wind_gust": return arrWind_Gust1;
            case "temperature": return arrTemperature1;
            case "wind_direction": return arrWind_Direction1;
            case "weather": return arrWeather1;
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

and so on...
which is parsed an populated via this AsyncTask:

```
public class JSONWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather> {

    @Override
    protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
        String data = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0], params[1]));
        Weather forecast = new Weather();
        try {
            forecast = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return forecast;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather){
        super.onPostExecute(weather);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FragmentStatePagerSupportActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

which on PostExecute calls another activity class (FragmentPagerSupportActivity). 
The question is: How to pass the already populated "Weather weather" to the activity?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the suggestions above I encountered several problems and the code was getting extended beyond my abilities. Instead of Parcelable or Serialized I decided to put the following inner class in the originating activity:

```
static public class ManageData {
    static Weather weather;
    static public Weather getData(){
        return weather;
    }
    static public void putData(Weather forecast) {
        weather = forecast;

    }
}
```

and then in the receiving activity:

```
Weather forecast = splash_activity.ManageData.getData();
```

And it works. Would someone knowledgeable let me know if I'm shooting in my foot with this approach?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way will be to serialize the object, using Gson for example:

```
 String serializedObject = new Gson().toJson(forecast);
```

and pass it with intent extra:

```
intent.putExtra("weatherObject", serializedObject);
```

Then in the recieving activity deserialize your object:

```
Type typeOfT = new TypeToken<forecast>() {
        }.getType();

        forecast = new Gson().fromJson(serializedObject , typeOfT);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to transfer the weather object to the activity. You can use [parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for that.